# Is there a way for two People to work on one Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, collaboration

A friend of mine and me are doing some field research for our Physics degree. And we are using jupyter notebook to analyse the data we get. We usually sit together working at two different copies of the same file that in the end will be drag and dropped together using jupyter lab. This is obviously not ideal, so i thought is there any way for just two people to work on one document in Jupyter, sadly Google Colab has been Deprecated and CoCalc is expensive. So i thought id ask here if there is a way to make one person run a Jupyter notebook and the other one just being able to access it over peer to peer aswell so we could write in the same file at the same time.
Do you guys know something that makes me do this maybe a workaround that i can do.
Thanks for answers in advance

Comment: you should use GitHub for this.

Comment: Is Google Colab really deprecated? I see Jupyter colaboratory is indeed deprecated [1], but the Google colab tools repo [2] is active (commits, issues) and the stackoverflow tag is active [3].

[1] https://github.com/jupyter/colaboratory
[2] https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools
[3] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-colaboratory

Comment: @Sheri this won't work well with jupiter notebooks, as they contain way more than just code

Comment: Google Colab is not deprecated: https://colab.research.google.com. Where did you get this information from?

Comment: what i mean is that google colabs Colaboratory functions are deprecated. You cant work with multiple people efficently in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> CoCalc is expensive.

Fortunately, we also provide a [complete free easy to install open source version of CoCalc](https://github.com/sagemathinc/cocalc-docker/blob/master/README.md), which you can run on any computer that supports Docker.   For example, here's [how to run it on Google cloud](https://blog.cocalc.com/cocalc/2018/11/07/cocalc-docker-gcp.html).

(I have put too many years of my life into making realtiime collaboration work for Jupyter via CoCalc...  In any case, [the open source code](https://github.com/sagemathinc/cocalc/tree/master/src/smc-util/sync) has been battle tested in production for a while now and is working well finally.  I hope it can solve your problem...)

Comment: this literally made my day 100% Better that is so dope good job. and thanks for the answer

Answer (score 6):

You can upload your notebook to [Deepnote](https://deepnote.com). It provides a hosted environment, where you and your colleague can connect at the same time and work on the same notebook in real-time (the same way you'd do in Google Docs).

[Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook) is also good, but writing at the same time will result in conflicts.

Comment: I have been beta testing Deepnote for quite some time now and its amazing.

Comment: can you use COLAB as like as two users can edit a google sheets or can tow developers can use Live Share in VSC

Answer (score 2):

Notebook itself doesn't support to collaborate simultaneously, but you can use GitHub to manage your python script and upload it into Colab separately. This way Github can help manage the file history and solve the conflicts.

Comment: Coming back to this, Jupyter now supports real time collaboration via the --collaborative flag.

Answer (score 2):

JupyterLab 3.1.0a7 introduced real time collaboration.

There is [a screencast](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/6ce26381703355e0ef1da4af742b7f72#features) showing it in action.
Key thing to note is the new top-level menu item called **Share**, to the right of **Settings** & **Help**.

---

You can click on `launch binder` [here](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/6ce26381703355e0ef1da4af742b7f72) or [here](https://github.com/firasm/RTC_test) to try it now.

> "Once you see the JupyterLab interface, there's a new top-level menu item called "Share"; click that, grab and share that URL, and you're done!"-SOURCE: Step #5 [here](https://github.com/firasm/RTC_test#instructions)

There's a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/6ce26381703355e0ef1da4af742b7f72) that seems to be updated regularly with how to activate the feature.

There's a detailed walk-through [here](https://github.com/firasm/RTC_test#instructions) if you want to add the ability into your own repositories that can launch via MyBinder.org. Although if that repo falls behind [the gist](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/6ce26381703355e0ef1da4af742b7f72), you'll probably want to consult [the gist](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/6ce26381703355e0ef1da4af742b7f72) for the current best practices once you have the idea from the detailed walk-through.

---

---

Closely related question with an answer by @krassowski, is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68551456/8508004). You may want to look there for some additional details.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use github for this it can get messy, many people clear output cells when committing to git to avoid conflict issues. Which would defeat the object of your review work.

You should try [Curvenote](https://curvenote.com) (which we're building for that reason) it doesn't offer compute as its a collaborative writing tool, works on top of Jupyter via a chrome extenson and gives you real time versioning, commenting and diffs.

Answer (score 1):

> Google Colab has been Deprecated and CoCalc is expensive

**[Noteable.io](https://noteable.io)** is 100% free for all users including storage, compute, RAM. For your purposes, it will be ideal as you will get Google Drive like collaboration (commenting, @mentioning, Annotating data points), versioning, sharing, interactive visualizations, choice of using Python and SQL in the same notebook and a ton of other features.

Here are good example notebooks on Noteable:

1. [Climate Change: An analysis of Dew Point for the city of Toronto](https://app.noteable.io/f/f2e95d5b-288b-4afd-8a7f-38288c89b854/Climate-Change%3A-An-Analysis-of-Dew-Point-for-the-City-of-Toronto.ipynb)
2. [Healthcare Sector Employee Attrition Exploratory Data Analysis](https://app.noteable.io/f/d78d151f-e463-4f55-a2a8-b67f9315b58a/Exploratory-Data-Analysis%3A-Employee-Retention-at-a-Healthcare-Company.ipynb)
3. [Exploratory Data Analysis Using SQL and Python - Online Retailer Orders](https://app.noteable.io/f/9d877fbd-4bb4-41ca-bf11-c7f48f0ccc20/Exploratory-Data-Analysis-Using-SQL-and-Python---Online-Retailer-Orders.ipynb)

Comment: This is realy cool thank you for sharing this.