# What is the difference between `jupyter notebook` and `jupyter server`?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Running `jupyter notebook` and `jupyter server` give me very similar results and the descriptions are also quite similar.

```
❯ jupyter notebook -h
The Jupyter HTML Notebook.

This launches a Tornado based HTML Notebook Server that serves up an
HTML5/Javascript Notebook client.

❯ jupyter server -h
The Jupyter Server.

This launches a Tornado-based Jupyter Server.
```

There are differences like `server` doesn't load `nbextensions` but I don't understand why there are two commands that have so much overlap.

For reference, this are the versions of various modules.

```
❯ jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.3.0
qtconsole        : 5.0.3
ipython          : 7.22.0
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.12
jupyter lab      : 3.0.11
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.6.3
nbformat         : 5.1.3
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Jupyter Notebook (`notebook` module) prior to v7 contained both:

- the server for notebooks (the backend of the web application that hosts the notebook contents, proxies interaction with kernels, and interacts with the operating system by e.g. opening an internet browser on start; this part is generally written in Python), and
- the client (the frontend of the web application, e.g. HTML code, javascript, and some extra REST API points on the server).

However, because there are now multiple clients (frontends) providing different web applications for notebooks:

- Jupyter Notebook
- JupyterLab
- [RetroLab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/retrolab)
- [nteract](https://nteract.io)
- multiple proprietary clients developed outside of project Jupyter

It made sense to split the server component used by all of these so that e.g. JupyterLab does not have to depend on notebook. This also means that if a fix to the server component is needed, it can be released quickly independent of Jupyter Notebook release cycle (and users of all frontents can benefit immediately).

As a consequence, and to make the break up clean, the old Jupyter Notebook was split into:

- [jupyter-server](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server) - the server which was adapted by JuptyterLab, RetroLab, nteract
- [nbclassic](https://github.com/jupyterlab/nbclassic) - the Jupyter Notebook as a jupyter-server extension

This implies changes for users and developers, some already described in ["migrate from notebook"](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators/migrate-from-nbserver.html#migrate-from-notebook) docs:

- the options specific to server rather than notebook were renamed from  `c.NotebookApp` to `c.ServerApp` (the options specific to notebook remain `c.NotebookApp`)
- the server-specific configuration is now stored in `jupyter_server_config.py` rather than `jupyter_notebook_config.py` (same for `.json` version)
- users should now use `jupyter server extension` rather than `jupyter serverextension` (note the extra space!) to list, enable or disable extensions
- the server extensions need to place their files in a new location: `etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.d` rather than `etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.d` (in practice most extensions that were updated to support jupyter server are now placing files in both locations for backward compatibility with notebook, but this will change in the future)

It is important to note that depending on how you start your jupyter notebook, you will see different servers being used:

- `jupyter nbclassic` (assuming nbclassic is installed) will use the new `jupyter-server`
- `jupyter notebook` will use the old `notebook` server
- `jupyter lab` will use new `jupyter-server` starting with JupyterLab 3.0 unless running on JupyterHub/Binder where it might still be using old `notebook` server, depending on configuration

This also implies that you may see different extensions when running `jupyter notebook` vs `jupyter nbclassic` (depending on whether their developers updated the locations, and whether they decided they want to support the legacy `notebook` server).

The creation of `nbclassic` replacement rather than removal of the server code from existing `notebook` package was meant to ensure backward compatibility, and this is why you still have two copies of the Tornado server (one provided by `jupyter notebook` and one by `jupyter server`). To make the situation simpler you could remove `notebook` and install `nblcassic`, but given that the transition is in progress you may need to adjust a few things manually. However, this is only a temporary situation, and starting with Notebook v7.0 it also migrated to use `jupyter server`.

This might look inconvenient for now, but this step ensures greater maintainability of the core Jupyter infrastructure in the future and will benefit users and system admins greatly later on.

Comment: Thank you for the super detailed answer!

Comment: Good explanation! The big question here is, how we know which configuration goes now to jupyter_server_config.py and which is kept in jupyter_notebook_config.py?
I have tried ```jupyter server --generate-config``` and ```jupyter notebook --generate-config``` but there is a lot of overlap there.