# is it possible to hide kernels from the jupyterlab launcher?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am working in Jupyterlab and I'm using voila to create dashboard application based on notebooks. Each aaplication lives withit's own set of dependancies thus a specific kernel (venv) is created for every single one of them.

My problem is that all these kernels are register in my jupyterlab env and displayed in the launcher as shown here:

[image]

I would like to hide them from jupyterlab so that they don't apear in the kernel list. Following this documentation (https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html) and other posts on SO, I created a notebook config file:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

and added this configuration to the file :

```py
c.KernelSpecManager.whitelist = set('ir', 'javascript', 'python3')
```

but it didn't change anything to the launcher. Is there another way or did I miss something ?

Comment: If JupyterLab >= 3 you very likely should be using `jupyter server` not `jupyter notebook`; Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/67804732/6646912 for more. The docs are on https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/other/full-config.html#other-full-config

Comment: Ok so I've tried your solution but then the kernel cannot be used anymore, which is preventing to use them when I run the apps with the voila cli. Is there a way to only hide them in the launcher ?

Comment: You could create a JupyterLab extension to hide them. If you just want to visually hide them, a simple CSS rule would suffice (you can query on `title` attribute)