# why voila is not working with jupyter lab

Tags: python, macos, jupyter, jupyter-lab, voila

I recently installed jupyter lab on my macos, and I'm trying to use it with voila.
The installation process was the following:

1. `pip3 install jupyterlab`
2. `pip3 install voila`
3. `jupyter serverextension enable voila`

Now when using the command `jupyter serverextension list` it seems to be installed and activated correctly.
Now the problem is that after running jupyter lab, if I follow the instruction in the documentation typing /voila, it says:

```
Path not found
The path: /lab/voila was not found. JupyterLab redirected to: /
```

Another thing that I tried is to use the command `!voila my_code.ip` and the resulting error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/voila", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 975, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/voila/app.py", line 374, in initialize
    self.setup_template_dirs()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/voila/app.py", line 380, in setup_template_dirs
    self.template_paths = collect_template_paths(['voila', 'nbconvert'], template_name, prune=True)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/voila/paths.py", line 24, in collect_template_paths
    return collect_paths(app_names, template_name, include_root_paths=True, prune=prune, root_dirs=root_dirs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/voila/paths.py", line 90, in collect_paths
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: No template sub-directory with name 'base' found in the following paths:
```

I already tried to uninstall an reinstall both jupyter and voila.
What am I doing wrong? I would prefer to use the first method since giving the command only at the end of the code would be quite uncomfortable for me and I would like to render the result in the same page (or at least open the final result in a new page with only a button).
Please I really don't know what to do.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: What about `jupyter server extension list`? It is possible that you only enabled it for the old notebook server, not the new `jupyter-server` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67797152/what-is-the-difference-between-jupyter-notebook-and-jupyter-server/67804732).

Comment: Yes thank you. It seems that I was installing and enabling it on a different server